# Azure Mobile Services Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am playing with Azure Mobile Services and am trying to integrate blob storage with my iOS application.  The code below is working to download a single blob.  I do have a few questions on how WAMS server scripts work.

1) blobService.getBlobToFile writes a file to the file system.  I didn't expect to have access to a file system.  Are the files that you create temporary per request?  Do you need to clean them up after using them?  Is it visible in some manner through the portal?

2) I originally tried to use blobService.getBlob as seen on the [github repo](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js).  It seemed to be a cleaner method of returning a blob.  However, when i tried to use it, it didn't exist on Azure.  Is this not available?

3) In general, I'm having trouble finding what I can actually do within the server scripting environment.  Can you point me to documentation on all of the modules and functions that are available?

```
var azure = require('azure');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.get = function(request, response) {

    var accountName = '<ACCOUNT_NAME>';
    var accountKey = '<ACCOUNT_KEY>';
    var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);

    blobService.getBlobToFile('icons', 'image1.png', 'tempfile', function(error, blockBlob, response) {
        if(error){
            request.respond(500);
        }else{
            fs.readFile('tempfile', function (err, data) {
                if(error){
                    request.respond(500);
                }
                else{
                    request.respond(200, data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, these should be considered temporary files.  Azure can always move your service from one machine to another at which time all those temporary files are gone.  Don't know what exactly happens when the machine is there for long and the temp folder grows too huge.
2. I don't think this repo is relevant to the problem you are looking at.
3. Here is a good walkthrough: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/upload-images-to-storage-dotnet/#update-scripts

Comment: I ended up deciding not to use mobile services but thanks for the answer